# Gmail Log in with Selenium Python does not work

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to login at Google with Selenium and Python, but there's always an error "The Browser is not secure". I read that Google detects the automation and throws an error then. One guy here said that it's possible to just login trough another Page using Google, but it does not work anymore. So how can I login at Google using Selenium and Python?

Or to specify it more:
I am looking for a verification code that was sent to the email, is there a better way to get it?

Comment: The browser knows that you are using automation software, and probably passes this information to websites. Gmail probably doesn't allow you to log in for security purposes.

Comment: Check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78148407/3806036

Answer (score 0):

While trying to login into *GMail* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), this error...

[image: This browser or app may not be secure]

...implies there can be either/all of the following issues:

- [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en): If an app or site doesn’t meet Google's [security standards](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#more-secure-apps-how), Google might block anyone who’s trying to sign in to your account from it. Less secure apps can make it easier for hackers to get in to your account, so blocking sign-ins from these apps helps keep your account safe.
- *If "Less secure app access" is on for your account*: Because less secure apps can make your account more vulnerable, Google will automatically turn this setting off if it’s not being used. If "Less secure app access" is still on for your account, its recommended turning it off now and switching to more secure apps. To Turn off "Less secure app access":

  - Go to the [Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4MmOPP_ZAOaIp-wL6A0TanrVQc7gEN1Bc5cekNWSR6b2vBzA1z-DaKyJdxYfra9lmv4N75KbQgMepcZ3qUhEgKEZiuRIw) section of your Google Account. You might need to sign in.
  - Turn **Allow less secure apps** off.
- *If "Less secure app access" is off for your account*: If "Less secure app access" is turned off for your account, you can [turn it back on](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4O8PBsk_R-uLT9XPiXK-B3CSnVrbCV9UDgVtNS20lfRZh3vc1utaJXLlkKY9tWEmSq_UXSPANY-IWe13hBTNqkyCksGdA). It is recommend switching to more secure apps instead.

Comment: Thanks for that reply, but I did not really understand wheter I have to turn "Allow less secure apps" on or off to avoid googles error message?

Comment: Ok. No matter if "Allow less secure apps" is switched on or off. The error is thrown.